# How to declare the table name as an argument with GRDB

Tags: swift, sqlite

The function below works fine if I replace the ? with the name of one of the tables and remove the argument. However, I need the table name to be declared with the variable (theTable). I did't find a solution in the GRDB documentation.

This is the part that I need help with SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY Num.

This is the error:
Fetching figure list failed: SQLite error 1: near "?": syntax error - while executing SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY Num

Thanks for the help.

```
import UIKit
import GRDB

struct FigureList: Codable, FetchableRecord, TableRecord
{
    let FigureID: Int64
    var notes: String?
    var theDescription: String
    var Num: String
    var manufNum: String?
    var catagory: String?
}


static func getFigureList() -> [FigureList]
{
    var theArray = [FigureList]()
    let theTable = gTheCollection
    
    do {
        try Database.shared.databaseConnection!.read { db in
           theArray = try FigureList.fetchAll(db, sql: "SELECT * FROM ? ORDER BY Num", arguments: [theTable])
        }
    } catch {
        print("Fetching figure list failed: \(error)")
    }
    
    return theArray
}
```

Comment: sqlite does not allow parameter substitution for table or column names. String manipulation is usually required to build the query.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just use a switch statement.